# How can to change ui-icon's color in PrimeFaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, colors, icons

I am developing a Web Java Application with JSF 2.2 and PrimeFaces 6.0. I am building a `p:tree` and I would like to change the ui-icons color as, for example, in the next picture (the text is censoring).

[image]

My xhtml code is:

```
<p:tree value="#{docBean.root}" var="doc">
    <p:treeNode expandedIcon="ui-icon-folder-open" collapsedIcon="ui-icon-folder-collapsed">
        <h:outputText value="#{doc.name}" />
    </p:treeNode>
</p:tree>
```

I tried with...

```
.ui-icon-folder-open{
    color: red;
}
```

...but the just icon background changed to red.

Thank you!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For me the most flexible and easiest solution is to use font-awesome 'icons' for the nodes. They are not effectively icons but as the name states, fonts. So these **can** be changed by css. Hence their popularity and why they are also [included in PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/fa.xhtml)

The [PrimeFaces showcase for tree with icons](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/tree/icon.xhtml) shows that you can add custom icons for nodes, both the open and closed ones and also for the leaves. Luckily everything you add in the corresponding attributes client-side ends up in 'class' attributes on the html AND you can add multiple white space values in the attributes. This is what font-awesome needs, so by adding `expandedIcon="fa fa-folder-open"` or `collapsedIcon="fa fa-folder"` you can get the right icons and with a default style of `.fa { color: orange}` you get exactly what you want.

[image]

In a full example with changed leaves would be something like this:

```
<style>

    .fa { 
        color: orange;
    }

</style>
<h:form>
   <p:tree value="#{treeIconView.root}" var="doc">
        <p:treeNode expandedIcon="fa fa-folder-open" collapsedIcon="fa fa-folder">
            <h:outputText value="#{doc.name}"/>
        </p:treeNode>

        <p:treeNode type="document" icon="fa fa-file-o">
            <h:outputText value="#{doc.name}" />
        </p:treeNode>

        <p:treeNode type="picture" icon="fa fa-file-picture-o">
            <h:outputText value="#{doc.name}" />
        </p:treeNode>

        <p:treeNode type="mp3" icon="fa fa-file-video-o">
            <h:outputText value="#{doc.name}" />
        </p:treeNode>
    </p:tree>
</h:form>
```

But you can go a lot further. Look at the following image:

[image]

It is produced with the following example:

```
<style>

    .fa { 
        color: orange;
    }

    .videoColor {
        color: blue;
    }

    .colorOpen {
        color: green;
    }

    .fa-file-picture-o {
        color: purple;
    }

    .color30KB {
        color: red;
    }

</style>
<h:form>
    <p:tree value="#{treeIconView.root}" var="doc">
        <p:treeNode expandedIcon="fa fa-folder-open colorOpen" collapsedIcon="fa fa-folder">
            <h:outputText value="#{doc.name}"/>
        </p:treeNode>

        <p:treeNode type="document" icon="fa fa-file-o">
            <h:outputText value="#{doc.name}" />
        </p:treeNode>

        <p:treeNode type="picture" icon="fa fa-file-picture-o #{doc.size == '30 KB' ? 'color30KB' : '' }">
            <h:outputText value="#{doc.name}" />
        </p:treeNode>

        <p:treeNode type="mp3" icon="fa fa-file-video-o videoColor">
            <h:outputText value="#{doc.name}" />
        </p:treeNode>
    </p:tree>
</h:form>
```

You can add additional 'classes' in the icon attributes, but you can also use the fa classes that are already added and use that in css selectors, or you can add specific conditional 'classes' in the icons based on values etc... And since it can all be changed by css, you can not only change the color, but also the size, rotation, css animations or whatever.

Comment: Its very different ui-icon and fa-icon. THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Comment: With such a big thank you, why not also upvote the answer ;-)

Comment: If you are "stuck" with an existing project full of UI icons, you could try [`FontAwesomeResourceHandler`](https://github.com/jepsar/Jepsar-PrimeFaces-Theme#fontawesomeresourcehandler)

Comment: Cool a downvote on this answer without a comment while it has many upvotes